# vsftpd email notification

Tags: ubuntu, email, ftp, vsftpd

i'm using vsftp on ubuntu 9.04 Is it possible to send an email whenever a user uploads a file to a particular folder using ftp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think vsftpd itself has anything that will do this for you.  Most likely you'll have to write / find a script that will watch a particular directory for files, and email it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable logging for vsftp and then look for files being uploaded in taget directory.

```
 #!/bin/sh

 tail -F /var/log/vsftpd.log | while read line; do
     if echo "$line" | grep -q '/path/to/target/folder'; then
          echo "File is uploaded" | /usr/sbin/sendmail "foo@bar.com";
     fi
 done
```

Comment: what if the vsftp log rotates - the script will go idle